# Wordpress anchor tag contents moved out after switching to visual and back to text mode

Tags: wordpress

Using `<a name="foobar">Hello</a>` in the text mode editor and switching to visual mode and back to text editor results in 'Hello'. Using latest wordpress 4.8.2. Anchor tag itself works but not sure why the contents are moved out of the a tag. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of TinyMCE - the default WP editor, and also used in many other applications.

The format you are using is valid according to the [HTML 4.01 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#anchors-with-id):

```
<a name="foobar">Hello</a>
```

However when you use TinyMCE to insert anchors into content, it uses the following format:

```
<a name="foobar"></a>
```

...and it appears that it enforces this structure, even if you manually add an anchor manually with text between the tag.

**However, you can use any tag (not just `<a>`) to define the anchor point**, if you need to have text in your anchor. The following example from the [HTML 4.01 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#anchors-with-id) shows an id on a h2 tag being used as the anchor:

```
<a href="#section2">Section Two</a>

//...later in the document
<h2 id="section2">Section Two</h2>
```

So if you want to keep the structure you have, you can change your anchor to

```
<a href="#foobar">Go to foobar</a>
[...]
<p id="foobar">Hello</a>
```

***Note on HTML5*** the `name` attribute of the `<a>` tag has been deprecated in HTML 5 - use `id` instead

Hope that helps :)